# Is namespace desired in a jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, namespaces

My favorite design pattern to create a jQuery plugin is shown below.

Is there any reason to create a namespace for methods in the plugin?  Specifically, my use of `var privateMethods` shown below?

```
(function($){
    var privateMethods={};
    privateMethods.method1=function(){alert('privateMethods1');};
    privateMethods.method2=function(){alert('privateMethods2');};
    privateMethods.method3=function(){alert('privateMethods3');};

    var privateMethod1=function(){alert('privateMethods1');};
    var privateMethod2=function(){alert('privateMethods2');};
    var privateMethod3=function(){alert('privateMethods3');};

    function privateFunction1(){
        //Consider using this approach if there is significant script
        alert('privateFunction1');
    }

    var defaults = {    //private, right?
        foo: 'bar'
    };

    var methods = {
        init : function (options) {
            var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            return this.each(function () {
                //do whatever
            });
        },
        destroy : function () {
            return this.each(function () {});
        },
        otherPublicMethod : function() {
            return $(this).each(function(){
                //do whatever
            })
        }
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlugin');
        }    
    };
    }(jQuery)
);
```

Comment: Yes, if you want a 3rd party developer to be able to extend your plugin to fit their needs in the event they have a special use case. I would make that namespace available so that it can be extended/overridden as needed. `$.fn.myPlugin.privateMethods = {}` for example.

Comment: @KevinB  Do I need to do anything more than I show for `privateMethods` to make it available?

Comment: Yes, because currently the only way to override/extend it would be to edit the js directly. `$.fn.myPlugin._ = privateMethods` at the end would be enough. could do the same with `methods`.

Comment: @KevinB.  Thanks, that makes sense.  Would I also want to do something like `var privateMethods = privateMethods || {};`, or just as I showed it?  Also, I see you used `_` as the name.  What I then use `_` as the namespace when calling any of the private methods from within the plugin?

Comment: No, nothing inside the plugin has to change, other than adding that one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the visibility of your methods outside your plugins scope there is no difference between

- `privateMethods.method`
- `privateMethod1 = function(){}`
- `function privateFunction(){}`

On the other hand namespacing does not have any serious drawbacks apart from the slightly bigger size your jQuery plugin will have (easily mitigated by mini- and uglifying your code). The possible advantages are the possibilities to:

- Introduce a logical structure to your code by breaking your methods into namespaced groups
- Use well-known Javascript patterns around Namespaces, making your code readable and maintainable e.g.: http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/
- Encapsulation. Gets relevant for plugins with massive code base

In conclusion: Overall I'd opt to use namespaces anytime.